# CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() very slow to trigger registered cancellation delegates

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I'm having an issue with HTTP request cancellations in a blazor server app.  I have a web app that uses Google Maps with custom tile overlays.  The map will request 256x256 tiles from my server as the user zooms around.  As the user zooms around, Google Maps, appropriately, cancels any pending HTTP requests that are no longer needed.  If, however, the user moves around quickly, a lot of cancellations happen. Something in the server is getting delayed because of all the cancellations.
To attempt to debug this, I made a simple console app that uses Task.Delay taking a cancellation token.
With relatively few tasks going (2x # of logical cores)), things work as expected.  As the number of tasks increases, the delay becomes extreme.
I've made a GitHub repo demonstrating all of this at: https://github.com/TNT0305/TestWait

Near the top of main, there are some configuration parameters:

- induceDelay - set to true to increase the number of tasks to manifest the issue (default to false)
- taskDelayMs - number of milliseconds to Task.Delay in each call (defaults to 20000ms)

On my machine, with induceDelay set to true, I get 512 calls to the task.  After 100ms, I call Cancel() on the cancellation token source.  It takes 18.4 seconds for the call to Cancel() to return.

I think I must be missing something.  Any ideas?

### Clarification

The issues are not, necessarily, how long it takes for .Cancel() to return.  It has to do with how long it takes for the cancel to be detected in the async task after the .Cancel() call was initiated.

Here's the `Program.cs` from the GitHub repo:

```cs
using System.Text;

namespace testWait
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class to record information on timing of tasks
    /// </summary>
    class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public bool CancelledBeforeStart { get; set; } = false;
        public DateTime? CancelTriggerTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CancelExceptionTime { get; set; }

        // Properties to make sense of the recorded times
        public double TotalDuration { get => (EndTime - StartTime).TotalSeconds; }
        public double TriggeredAfter {  get => CancelTriggerTime != null ? (CancelTriggerTime.Value - StartTime).TotalSeconds : -1.0; }
        public double ExceptionAfter { get => CancelExceptionTime != null ? (CancelExceptionTime.Value - StartTime).TotalSeconds : -1.0; }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Id},{StartTime},{TotalDuration},{TriggeredAfter},{ExceptionAfter},{CancelledBeforeStart}";
        public string ReportCancel(DateTime cancelTime)
        {
            var t = CancelTriggerTime != null ? (CancelTriggerTime.Value - cancelTime).TotalSeconds : -1.0;
            return $"{Id} cancel delegate called {t}s after cts.Cancel() was called";
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // RUN CONFIGURATION
            // set induceIssue to true to observe excessive delay.  Set to false to observe expected behaviors
            bool induceIssue = true;
            int taskDelayMs = 30000;    // Task.DelayAsync for 20 seconds
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // Hold results from all calls.  Outer Main has Id=-1
            List<Event> Events = new List<Event>();

            int taskCount = Environment.ProcessorCount << 1;    // twice as many tasks as logical cores
            if (induceIssue) taskCount = Environment.ProcessorCount << 5; // 2^5 as may tasks as cores

            Console.WriteLine($"Starting {taskCount} tasks on {Environment.ProcessorCount} Logical Cores");
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime end = start;
            var te = new Event
            {
                Id = -1,
                StartTime = start,
                EndTime = end
            };
            // Add the event representing the entire "Main"
            Events.Add(te);
            using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            
            // record the time when we detected the token was triggered
            cts.Token.Register(() => end = DateTime.Now);

            // create an array of cancellable tasks
            var tasks = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, taskCount) select DoSomething(i, taskDelayMs, cts.Token)).ToArray();
            // try with Task.Run to see if it makes a difference (it does now))
            //var tasks = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, taskCount) select Task.Run(async () => await DoSomething(i, taskDelayMs, cts.Token), cts.Token)).ToArray();

            // CancelAfter is what we want, but let's call cancel, explicitly, to observe delays
            //cts.CancelAfter(200);

            // wait 100ms to trigger the cancellation so that we have a chance to enter into the Task.Delay(...) calls
            DateTime cancelStart = DateTime.MinValue;
            var triggerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                cancelStart = DateTime.Now;
                var triggerTime = (cancelStart - start).TotalSeconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"Cancelling work after {triggerTime}s");
                cts.Cancel();
                DateTime cancelEnd = DateTime.Now;
                triggerTime = (cancelEnd - start).TotalSeconds;
                var cancelDuration = (cancelEnd - cancelStart).TotalSeconds;
                // report time at which the token source finished the call to Cancel() (observe long delay)
                Console.WriteLine($"After calling cancel: {triggerTime}s (ctr..Cancel() duration: {cancelDuration})");
                te.CancelTriggerTime = DateTime.Now;
            });

            try
            {
                // use wait instead of when to pass the token into the WaitAll rather than relying on "DoSomething"
                //Task.WaitAll(tasks, cts.Token);
                Events.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(tasks));
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
            {
                // records the time when the exception threw the OperationCancelledException (if it is thrown)
                te.CancelExceptionTime = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine("Main Task Cancelled Exception");
            }

            te.EndTime = DateTime.Now;

            var duration = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds;
            var cancelAfter = (end - start).TotalSeconds;

            await triggerTask;
            //wait for them all to _actually_ finish
            //Events.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(tasks));

            #region Build results String

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            // sort the events by when the cancellation token was triggered
            foreach (var e in Events.OrderBy(e => e.TriggeredAfter).ToList())
            {
                //sb.AppendLine(e.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine(e.ReportCancel(cancelStart));
            }

            #endregion

            // Write out all of the results
            Console.Write(sb.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine($"MainTask, taskDuration: {duration}, cancelAfter: {cancelAfter}");
            Console.WriteLine("Done processing. Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static async Task<Event> DoSomething(int i, int delayMs, CancellationToken token)
        {
            Event e = new();
            //lock (Events) Events.Add(e);
            try
            {
                e.Id = i;
                //lock(log) log.AppendLine($"{i} started");
                e.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                e.EndTime = e.StartTime;

                // record the time when we detected the token was triggered
                token.Register(() => e.CancelTriggerTime = DateTime.Now);

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    e.CancelledBeforeStart = true;
                    return e;
                }
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(delayMs, token);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
                {
                    e.CancelExceptionTime = DateTime.Now;
                }
                e.EndTime = DateTime.Now;
                //await Task.Delay(20);
                return e;
            }
            finally
            {
                e.EndTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Cancel()` isn't `Abort()`. It raises signals the CancellationToken so the *consumers* can check it and exit gracefully. If the consumer doesn't check the token, or checks it only after completing a long-running operation, cancellation will be delayed

Comment: Agreed, Panagiotis.  In the awaited "DoSomething" call in the example, I register a handler on the cancellation token and record the time it happened.  After all tasks have completed, I sort them by how long after app start their cancellation tokens were triggered.  The most recently added task gets cancelled first.  The oldest task gets its delegate called last (on my machine, after 18.1 seconds).  Why is it taking so long for the trigger to manifest?  What is it waiting for?

Comment: [mcve] required.

Comment: Post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem in the question itself. `As the number of tasks increases, the delay becomes extreme` a computer can't execute more threads than cores at any time. If you schedule 1000 tasks on a dual-core, only 2 will run at any time. `If, however, the user moves around quickly, a lot of cancellations happen.` with 1 user shouldn't there be only 1 operation at a time? Besides, HTTP requests can't be cancelled unless the API allows it. You can only stop awaiting a response. Are you sure you aren't getting throttled by Google?

Comment: I though the testWait github I linked was a minrep example. In this example, I am _only_ calling Task.Delay (so, no significant processor utilization).   It is only as complex as it is to record the times at which each event happened during the flow of operation.  And Tasks are _not_ threads.  As the example is not doing any actual work, even with only one core, _should_ terminate pretty quickly after the cancellation token source is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bah.  Slow exception reporting in Visual Studio when run in debug mode.  When I run it in release mode, it runs as expected.
My original problem involves more components than my example uses and the downstream code had issues that I already corrected.

Takeaway: If you are having performance issues, try it outside the debugger (Ctrl+F5 instead of F5, in VS). >.<